# IFDEF in if condition

Tags: c++

Is it possible to use #ifdef macro in a if condition like this?

```
if(Something() || SomethingElse() #ifdef __TEST__ || SomethingTest()#endif )
{
// Code Sequence
}
```

Comment: yes, if you put it on several lines.

Comment: That seems like a pretty easy thing to test yourself... is there any particular reason you didn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,  just add some newlines.  The `#ifdef` and `#endif` need to be on their own lines:

```
if(Something() || SomethingElse()
    #ifdef __TEST__
    || SomethingTest()
    #endif
    )
{
    // Code Sequence
}
```

Comment: Or, if you want your code to be more readable, use the `#ifdef` stuff to define some `bool` variables beforehand, and then write the `if` condition in terms of those variables.

Comment: Agreed.  Or a macro.  #ifdefs can get out of control and make the code very difficult to maintain, so be as conservative as possible.